# Using filters to redirect from HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: ssl, glassfish, servlet-filters

I have few pages in my application which run on https://localhost:8181 and few pages which run on http://localhost:8080.I want to downshift from https to http but not sure how to go about it.I know I have to use filter which manages the redirection from https to http and http to https.

I looked into this link  [How to downshift from HTTPS to HTTP in your web application][1]

[1]: https://blogs.oracle.com/jluehe/entry/how_to_downshift_from_https  but the link where the filters s used are broken..I do not have a clear idea as to what is supposed to be done inside the filters...

In my web.xml `

```
  <filter>
      <filter-name>Non SSL port</filter-name>
      <filter-class>SSLFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
      <param-name>httpPort</param-name>
      <param-value>8080</param-value>
    </init-param>   
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>NON SSL pages</filter-name>    
    <url-pattern>/pages/success.xhtml</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/pages/failure.xhtml</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/pages/about.xhtml</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>`
```

CAn some one guide me what needs to be done inside the filter so that the shifting between https to http is smooth.

I am using Glassfish 3.1.1 and JSF.

Comment: The blog page, as most of the former sun pages, has been moved to oracle. Looks like they did not fix the links in it. Try replacing `sun` with `oracle` in the links. Worked at least for the `sample.war`. Leave them a comment, so they can fix it.

Answer (score 7):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;  
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;  

public class HttpsRedirectFilter implements Filter {

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, 
                      FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    if(request instanceof HttpServletRequest
         && response instanceof HttpServletResponse) {
        HttpServletRequest httpReq = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        String redirectTarget = httpReq.getRequestURL().toString();
        redirectTarget = redirectTarget.replaceFirst("https", "http")
        redirectTarget = redirectTarget.replaceFirst(":8443", ":8080");  
        redirectTarget = redirectTarget.replaceFirst("home", "home.do");  
        if(request.isSecure()) {                   
            ((HttpServletResponse)response).sendRedirect(redirectTarget);  
        } else {  
            chain.doFilter(request, response);  
        }  
    }  
}
}
```